# Displaying checkbox data when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to make multiple select with checkbox ... if I click checkbox A then checkbox B follow click too. But only the A checkbox that appears, the B checkbox I created in a hidden state with css ..

```
<button type="button" id="delete" title="Delete">Delete</button>

<input type="checkbox" class="select_data"  id="A" name="A[]" value="A" />
<input type="checkbox" class="info_del" id="B" name="B[]" value="B">

$('#delete').click(function() {
        if($('#A').is(":checked")) {
            $('#B').attr('checked', true).val();
         }

    var data = $(".select_data:checked, .info_del:checked").serialize();
    console.log(data);       
});
```

Comment: `if I click on checkbox A` but your click handlers id is `#delete` show all relevant code.. sample code is incomplete.. also description us not clear

Comment: Your element names `name="A[]"` and `name="B[]"` kind of imply you have a repeating group of these two checkboxes - if that's the case then giving them all the same `id` won't work. But either way I don't understand what you are asking. What is a "checkbox file"? What does "checkbox B is in type to hidden" mean? What are the other elements that your JS references but that aren't shown in the HTML? Please [edit] your question to show more of the HTML, and to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, For everything I apologize a bit hard to explain my problem and my english is also less good, for the question I have update hopefully can be understood.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a syntax issue with one line of your jQuery.

Try changing this line:

```
$('#B').attr('checked', true).val();
```

to:

```
$('#B').prop('checked', true);
```

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/qXOmoZ).